# Get properties of node using java embedded cypher query

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

currently have a cypher query method

```
public static void RunQuery(String _query)
{
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    final String DB_PATH = "path/to/db"
    GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
    ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDb);
    ExecutionResult result = engine.execute(_query);
    for(Map<String,Object> map : result)
    {
        System.out.println(map.toString());
    }
    graphDb.shutdown();


}
```

However this only allows me to get results like this:

```
{a=Node[11303]}
{a=Node[11341]}
{a=Node[11343]}
{a=Node[11347]}
{a=Node[11349]}
{a=Node[11378]}
```

How can I augment it to spit out the entire query results like the cypher shell does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does your query look like. The `Map<String, Object>` that is returned will have a key of the variable you return. The Object can be a Path, Node, or Relationship, and this will just call the native `toString()` on them, which in Java code just returns the Node ID. You have to build your own printer, something that will get the property keys and iterate through each of them.

```
for (String key : node.getPropertyKeys()) {
    System.out.println("Key: " + key + ", Value: " +  node.getProperty(key));
}
```

Comment: yes, I am looking for if the object is a node for it to print out the properties and values and if it is a value (such as a count) for it not to.  Essentially I want to recreate the console in the web interface or the neo4j-shell.

Comment: It's up to you to print out the properties, I don't believe Neo4j provides any convenience method for doing this, but you can do it in Java, I have modified my answer to include code for doing this.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas!  In your code, what is r and what is relationshipDto?

Comment: I have updated to code to make the object more have verbose names

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the `RETURN` of your query..

For example, if you have a query like this:

```
_query="Start x= node(someIndex) Match x-[rel:SOMETHING]-n Return n";
```

So, your code can be

```
    ExecutionResult result = engine.execute(_query);
    Iterator<Node> n_column = result.columnAs("n");
            for (Node outputNode: IteratorUtil.asIterable(n_column)) {
                System.out.println(outputNode.getProperty("yourKey","defaultValueIfNull"));
            }
```

Comment: this assumes that you know apriori that n is being returned.  I just want to return the string results of the query in order to replicate the neo4j-shell