# How to get a list of node properties with Cypher in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to list all of the properties for a set of nodes.

```
Match (n:"Indicator")
return properties(n), ID(n)
```

I'm unsure of the syntax and couldn't find the answer in the refcard or docs.

Comment: You can [do this with java][1], but you can't do it in Cypher, AFAIK.


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17412784/get-properties-of-node-using-java-embedded-cypher-query

Comment: interesting tidbits about this topic can be found in this abstract request
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FPfGkgzhcRXVkleBLBsA92U94Mx4yafu3nO-Xf-NzsE/edit#heading=h.pyvdg2rbofq

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Neo4j version 3.0.0 you may do:

```
Match (n:Indicator) return properties(n), ID(n)
```

To return the ID and properties of nodes.

Answer (score 5):

At the moment you can't do this using cypher but it is on the [top five](https://trello.com/c/FciCdgWl/7-cypher-property-container-functions) on the ideas board.

Answer (score 4):

```
MATCH (n)
RETURN DISTINCT keys(n), size(keys(n))
ORDER BY size(keys(n)) DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Properties(n) works if you need the properties of the node with the key and value, but if you only need to see the properties name's in a easy way you can do this.
Example:

```
MATCH (n:Indicator) return ID(n), keys(n), size(keys(n))
```

Results:
[image: Results from Neo4j browser]
<sub>Results from Neo4j browser</sub>

You can quit ID(n) and size(keys(n)) without problem but is good if you need to identify a node that dont have the required properties or is not complete.

Also you can use a DISTINCT if you have generic and repetitive properties on the same type of Node like this.

```
MATCH (n:Indicator) return DISTINCT ID(n), keys(n), size(keys(n))
```

As I have said this also works without problems and give you the array of properties that you need.

```
MATCH (n:Indicator) return keys(n)
```

[image: Result only returning keys]
<sub>Result only returning keys</sub>

But you can resume this long list of results, with a DISTINCT

```
MATCH (n:Indicator) return DISTINCT keys(n)
```

[image: Result with only the differents lists of properties that the Node (n) have]
<sub>Result with only the differents lists of properties that the Node (n) have</sub>

Comment: Underrated answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
MATCH (n:Label)
WITH DISTINCT(keys(n)) as key_sets
UNWIND(key_sets) as keys
RETURN DISTINCT(keys) as key
```

This will return a clean list of distinct keys

Answer (score 1):

If you have APOC installed, I use this to get a distinct list of all node property combinations:

```
MATCH (n) 
RETURN DISTINCT apoc.coll.sort(keys(n)) as props
               ,size(keys(n)) as key_size
```

Note: you don't *have* to use APOC, but if you don't you'll get duplicates where values are same, but ordering is different, so sorting combines them

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old, but when I had a similar question, I found the command below to be the solution that returned all the information I needed, which was to list out the properties for each node in the database, and include the property type(s) of each value for each node:

`CALL db.schema.nodeTypeProperties()`

Additionally, you can do the same thing for relationships:

`CALL db.schema.relTypeProperties()`

The nice part is that this will work with cypher shell and does not require APOC to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

in the case where the keys are returned in different orders, this does the trick:

```
MATCH (n)
UNWIND keys(n) AS allProps
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT allProps) as distinctProps
```